# configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables (ld: unknown option: -no_weak_imports)

Tags: macos, homebrew

I'm trying to get certain tools such as `wget` for my mac, and in my Internet adventures I stumbled upon this program called Homebrew, which seems like just the thing I need.

So I installed Homebrew using the script from their website, and everything ran OK. And after it finished, I ran `brew install wget`, but I got the following output:

```
Warning: You are using OS X 10.12.
We do not provide support for this pre-release version.
You may encounter build failures or other breakages.
Please create pull-requests instead of filing issues.
==> Installing dependencies for wget: xz, pkg-config, makedepend, openssl
==> Installing wget dependency: xz
==> Using the sandbox
==> Downloading https://fossies.org/linux/misc/xz-5.2.2.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> ./configure --disable-silent-rules --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/xz/5.2.2
Last 15 lines from /Users/chenjian/Library/Logs/Homebrew/xz/01.configure:
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... build-aux/install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking for gcc... clang
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/private/tmp/xz-20160817-3709-1qc3b72/xz-5.2.2':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

READ THIS: https://git.io/brew-troubleshooting
If reporting this issue please do so at (not Homebrew/brew):
  https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues

Warning: You are using OS X 10.12.
We do not provide support for this pre-release version.
You may encounter build failures or other breakages.
Please create pull-requests instead of filing issues.
```

TL;DR, I got the following error:

```
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/private/tmp/xz-20160817-3709-1qc3b72/xz-5.2.2':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

I checked my `config.log` as suggested, and found this out:

```
ld: unknown option: -no_weak_imports
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm guessing this was the problem, but in any case, here's the full `config.log`:

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by XZ Utils configure 5.2.2, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure --disable-debug --disable-dependency-tracking --disable-silent-rules --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/xz/5.2.2

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = Chens-MacBook-Pro.local
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 16.0.0
uname -s = Darwin
uname -v = Darwin Kernel Version 16.0.0: Fri Aug 12 19:00:53 PDT 2016; root:xnu-3789.1.28~1/RELEASE_X86_64

/usr/bin/uname -p = i386
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = Mach kernel version:
     Darwin Kernel Version 16.0.0: Fri Aug 12 19:00:53 PDT 2016; root:xnu-3789.1.28~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel configured for up to 8 processors.
4 processors are physically available.
8 processors are logically available.
Processor type: x86_64h (Intel x86-64h Haswell)
Processors active: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Primary memory available: 16.00 gigabytes
Default processor set: 345 tasks, 1496 threads, 8 processors
Load average: 2.33, Mach factor: 5.65
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/shims/super
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /sbin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2959: checking build system type
configure:2973: result: x86_64-apple-darwin16.0.0
configure:2993: checking host system type
configure:3006: result: x86_64-apple-darwin16.0.0
configure:3066: checking if debugging code should be compiled
configure:3082: result: no
configure:3122: checking which encoders to build
configure:3209: result: lzma1 lzma2 delta x86 powerpc ia64 arm armthumb sparc
configure:3213: checking which decoders to build
configure:3305: result: lzma1 lzma2 delta x86 powerpc ia64 arm armthumb sparc
configure:3644: checking which match finders to build
configure:3695: result: hc3 hc4 bt2 bt3 bt4
configure:3713: checking which integrity checks to build
configure:3755: result: crc32 crc64 sha256
configure:3792: checking if assembler optimizations should be used
configure:3816: result: no
configure:3847: checking if small size is preferred over speed
configure:3865: result: no
configure:3881: checking if threading support is wanted
configure:3907: result: yes, posix
configure:3940: checking how much RAM to assume if the real amount is unknown
configure:3955: result: 128 MiB
configure:4085: checking if library symbol versioning should be used
configure:4108: result: no
configure:4126: checking for a shell that conforms to POSIX
configure:4167: result: /bin/sh
configure:4208: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:4276: result: /usr/bin/install -c
configure:4287: checking whether build environment is sane
configure:4342: result: yes
configure:4493: checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p
configure:4532: result: build-aux/install-sh -c -d
configure:4539: checking for gawk
configure:4569: result: no
configure:4539: checking for mawk
configure:4569: result: no
configure:4539: checking for nawk
configure:4569: result: no
configure:4539: checking for awk
configure:4555: found /usr/bin/awk
configure:4566: result: awk
configure:4577: checking whether make sets $(MAKE)
configure:4599: result: yes
configure:4628: checking whether make supports nested variables
configure:4645: result: yes
configure:4771: checking whether ln -s works
configure:4775: result: yes
configure:4795: checking for style of include used by make
configure:4823: result: GNU
configure:4894: checking for gcc
configure:4921: result: clang
configure:5150: checking for C compiler version
configure:5159: clang --version >&5
Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.31)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.0.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
configure:5170: $? = 0
configure:5159: clang -v >&5
Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.31)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.0.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
configure:5170: $? = 0
configure:5159: clang -V >&5
clang: error: unsupported option '-V -isystem/usr/include/libxml2'
configure:5170: $? = 1
configure:5159: clang -qversion >&5
clang: error: unknown argument: '-qversion'
configure:5170: $? = 1
configure:5190: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:5212: clang    conftest.c  >&5
ld: unknown option: -no_weak_imports
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
configure:5216: $? = 1
configure:5254: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "XZ Utils"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "xz"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "5.2.2"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "XZ Utils 5.2.2"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "lasse.collin@tukaani.org"
| #define PACKAGE_URL "http://tukaani.org/xz/"
| #define NDEBUG 1
| #define HAVE_ENCODER_LZMA1 1
| #define HAVE_ENCODER_LZMA2 1
| #define HAVE_ENCODER_DELTA 1
| #define HAVE_ENCODER_X86 1
| #define HAVE_ENCODER_POWERPC 1
| #define HAVE_ENCODER_IA64 1
| #define HAVE_ENCODER_ARM 1
| #define HAVE_ENCODER_ARMTHUMB 1
| #define HAVE_ENCODER_SPARC 1
| #define HAVE_DECODER_LZMA1 1
| #define HAVE_DECODER_LZMA2 1
| #define HAVE_DECODER_DELTA 1
| #define HAVE_DECODER_X86 1
| #define HAVE_DECODER_POWERPC 1
| #define HAVE_DECODER_IA64 1
| #define HAVE_DECODER_ARM 1
| #define HAVE_DECODER_ARMTHUMB 1
| #define HAVE_DECODER_SPARC 1
| #define HAVE_MF_HC3 1
| #define HAVE_MF_HC4 1
| #define HAVE_MF_BT2 1
| #define HAVE_MF_BT3 1
| #define HAVE_MF_BT4 1
| #define HAVE_CHECK_CRC32 1
| #define HAVE_CHECK_CRC64 1
| #define HAVE_CHECK_SHA256 1
| #define ASSUME_RAM 128
| #define PACKAGE "xz"
| #define VERSION "5.2.2"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:5259: error: in `/private/tmp/xz-20160817-3709-1qc3b72/xz-5.2.2':
configure:5261: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=x86_64-apple-darwin16.0.0
ac_cv_env_CCASFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CCASFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CCAS_set=
ac_cv_env_CCAS_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_set=set
ac_cv_env_CC_value=clang
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_LT_SYS_LIBRARY_PATH_set=
ac_cv_env_LT_SYS_LIBRARY_PATH_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_host=x86_64-apple-darwin16.0.0
ac_cv_path_install='/usr/bin/install -c'
ac_cv_prog_AWK=awk
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=clang
ac_cv_prog_make_make_set=yes
am_cv_make_support_nested_variables=yes
gl_cv_posix_shell=/bin/sh

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ACLOCAL='${SHELL} /private/tmp/xz-20160817-3709-1qc3b72/xz-5.2.2/build-aux/missing aclocal-1.15'
AMDEPBACKSLASH=''
AMDEP_FALSE=''
AMDEP_TRUE='#'
AMTAR='$${TAR-tar}'
AM_BACKSLASH='\'
AM_CFLAGS=''
AM_DEFAULT_V='$(AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY)'
AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY='1'
AM_V='$(V)'
AR=''
AS=''
AUTOCONF='${SHELL} /private/tmp/xz-20160817-3709-1qc3b72/xz-5.2.2/build-aux/missing autoconf'
AUTOHEADER='${SHELL} /private/tmp/xz-20160817-3709-1qc3b72/xz-5.2.2/build-aux/missing autoheader'
AUTOMAKE='${SHELL} /private/tmp/xz-20160817-3709-1qc3b72/xz-5.2.2/build-aux/missing automake-1.15'
AWK='awk'
CC='clang'
CCAS=''
CCASDEPMODE=''
CCASFLAGS=''
CCDEPMODE=''
CFLAGS=''
CFLAG_VISIBILITY=''
COND_ASM_X86_64_FALSE=''
COND_ASM_X86_64_TRUE='#'
COND_ASM_X86_FALSE=''
COND_ASM_X86_TRUE='#'
COND_CHECK_CRC32_FALSE='#'
COND_CHECK_CRC32_TRUE=''
COND_CHECK_CRC64_FALSE='#'
COND_CHECK_CRC64_TRUE=''
COND_CHECK_SHA256_FALSE='#'
COND_CHECK_SHA256_TRUE=''
COND_DECODER_ARMTHUMB_FALSE='#'
COND_DECODER_ARMTHUMB_TRUE=''
COND_DECODER_ARM_FALSE='#'
COND_DECODER_ARM_TRUE=''
COND_DECODER_DELTA_FALSE='#'
COND_DECODER_DELTA_TRUE=''
COND_DECODER_IA64_FALSE='#'
COND_DECODER_IA64_TRUE=''
COND_DECODER_LZMA1_FALSE='#'
COND_DECODER_LZMA1_TRUE=''
COND_DECODER_LZMA2_FALSE='#'
COND_DECODER_LZMA2_TRUE=''
COND_DECODER_LZ_FALSE='#'
COND_DECODER_LZ_TRUE=''
COND_DECODER_POWERPC_FALSE='#'
COND_DECODER_POWERPC_TRUE=''
COND_DECODER_SIMPLE_FALSE='#'
COND_DECODER_SIMPLE_TRUE=''
COND_DECODER_SPARC_FALSE='#'
COND_DECODER_SPARC_TRUE=''
COND_DECODER_X86_FALSE='#'
COND_DECODER_X86_TRUE=''
COND_DOC_FALSE='#'
COND_DOC_TRUE=''
COND_ENCODER_ARMTHUMB_FALSE='#'
COND_ENCODER_ARMTHUMB_TRUE=''
COND_ENCODER_ARM_FALSE='#'
COND_ENCODER_ARM_TRUE=''
COND_ENCODER_DELTA_FALSE='#'
COND_ENCODER_DELTA_TRUE=''
COND_ENCODER_IA64_FALSE='#'
COND_ENCODER_IA64_TRUE=''
COND_ENCODER_LZMA1_FALSE='#'
COND_ENCODER_LZMA1_TRUE=''
COND_ENCODER_LZMA2_FALSE='#'
COND_ENCODER_LZMA2_TRUE=''
COND_ENCODER_LZ_FALSE='#'
COND_ENCODER_LZ_TRUE=''
COND_ENCODER_POWERPC_FALSE='#'
COND_ENCODER_POWERPC_TRUE=''
COND_ENCODER_SIMPLE_FALSE='#'
COND_ENCODER_SIMPLE_TRUE=''
COND_ENCODER_SPARC_FALSE='#'
COND_ENCODER_SPARC_TRUE=''
COND_ENCODER_X86_FALSE='#'
COND_ENCODER_X86_TRUE=''
COND_FILTER_ARMTHUMB_FALSE='#'
COND_FILTER_ARMTHUMB_TRUE=''
COND_FILTER_ARM_FALSE='#'
COND_FILTER_ARM_TRUE=''
COND_FILTER_DELTA_FALSE='#'
COND_FILTER_DELTA_TRUE=''
COND_FILTER_IA64_FALSE='#'
COND_FILTER_IA64_TRUE=''
COND_FILTER_LZMA1_FALSE='#'
COND_FILTER_LZMA1_TRUE=''
COND_FILTER_LZMA2_FALSE='#'
COND_FILTER_LZMA2_TRUE=''
COND_FILTER_LZ_FALSE='#'
COND_FILTER_LZ_TRUE=''
COND_FILTER_POWERPC_FALSE='#'
COND_FILTER_POWERPC_TRUE=''
COND_FILTER_SIMPLE_FALSE='#'
COND_FILTER_SIMPLE_TRUE=''
COND_FILTER_SPARC_FALSE='#'
COND_FILTER_SPARC_TRUE=''
COND_FILTER_X86_FALSE='#'
COND_FILTER_X86_TRUE=''
COND_GNULIB_FALSE=''
COND_GNULIB_TRUE=''
COND_INTERNAL_SHA256_FALSE=''
COND_INTERNAL_SHA256_TRUE=''
COND_LZMADEC_FALSE='#'
COND_LZMADEC_TRUE=''
COND_LZMAINFO_FALSE='#'
COND_LZMAINFO_TRUE=''
COND_LZMALINKS_FALSE='#'
COND_LZMALINKS_TRUE=''
COND_MAIN_DECODER_FALSE='#'
COND_MAIN_DECODER_TRUE=''
COND_MAIN_ENCODER_FALSE='#'
COND_MAIN_ENCODER_TRUE=''
COND_SCRIPTS_FALSE='#'
COND_SCRIPTS_TRUE=''
COND_SHARED_FALSE=''
COND_SHARED_TRUE=''
COND_SMALL_FALSE=''
COND_SMALL_TRUE='#'
COND_SYMVERS_FALSE=''
COND_SYMVERS_TRUE='#'
COND_THREADS_FALSE=''
COND_THREADS_TRUE=''
COND_W32_FALSE=''
COND_W32_TRUE='#'
COND_XZDEC_FALSE='#'
COND_XZDEC_TRUE=''
COND_XZ_FALSE='#'
COND_XZ_TRUE=''
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS=''
CYGPATH_W='echo'
DEFS=''
DEPDIR='.deps'
DLLTOOL=''
DSYMUTIL=''
DUMPBIN=''
ECHO_C='\c'
ECHO_N=''
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
EXEEXT=''
FGREP=''
GETOPT_H=''
GETTEXT_MACRO_VERSION=''
GMSGFMT=''
GMSGFMT_015=''
GREP=''
HAVE_VISIBILITY=''
INSTALL_DATA='${INSTALL} -m 644'
INSTALL_PROGRAM='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_SCRIPT='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM='$(install_sh) -c -s'
INTLLIBS=''
INTL_MACOSX_LIBS=''
LD=''
LDFLAGS=''
LIBICONV=''
LIBINTL=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LIBTOOL=''
LIPO=''
LN_EXEEXT='$(EXEEXT)'
LN_S='ln -s'
LTLIBICONV=''
LTLIBINTL=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
LT_SYS_LIBRARY_PATH=''
MAKEINFO='${SHELL} /private/tmp/xz-20160817-3709-1qc3b72/xz-5.2.2/build-aux/missing makeinfo'
MANIFEST_TOOL=''
MKDIR_P='build-aux/install-sh -c -d'
MSGFMT=''
MSGFMT_015=''
MSGMERGE=''
NM=''
NMEDIT=''
OBJDUMP=''
OBJEXT=''
OTOOL64=''
OTOOL=''
PACKAGE='xz'
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT='lasse.collin@tukaani.org'
PACKAGE_NAME='XZ Utils'
PACKAGE_STRING='XZ Utils 5.2.2'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='xz'
PACKAGE_URL='http://tukaani.org/xz/'
PACKAGE_VERSION='5.2.2'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
POSIX_SHELL='/bin/sh'
POSUB=''
PREFERABLY_POSIX_SHELL='/bin/sh'
PTHREAD_CC=''
PTHREAD_CFLAGS=''
PTHREAD_LIBS=''
RANLIB=''
RC=''
SED=''
SET_MAKE=''
SHELL='/bin/sh'
STRIP=''
USE_NLS=''
VERSION='5.2.2'
XGETTEXT=''
XGETTEXT_015=''
XGETTEXT_EXTRA_OPTIONS=''
ac_ct_AR=''
ac_ct_CC='clang'
ac_ct_DUMPBIN=''
am__EXEEXT_FALSE=''
am__EXEEXT_TRUE=''
am__fastdepCCAS_FALSE=''
am__fastdepCCAS_TRUE=''
am__fastdepCC_FALSE=''
am__fastdepCC_TRUE=''
am__include='include'
am__isrc=''
am__leading_dot='.'
am__nodep=''
am__quote=''
am__tar='$${TAR-tar} chof - "$$tardir"'
am__untar='$${TAR-tar} xf -'
ax_pthread_config=''
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='x86_64-apple-darwin16.0.0'
build_alias=''
build_cpu='x86_64'
build_os='darwin16.0.0'
build_vendor='apple'
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host='x86_64-apple-darwin16.0.0'
host_alias=''
host_cpu='x86_64'
host_os='darwin16.0.0'
host_vendor='apple'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
install_sh='${SHELL} /private/tmp/xz-20160817-3709-1qc3b72/xz-5.2.2/build-aux/install-sh'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
mkdir_p='$(MKDIR_P)'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='/usr/local/Cellar/xz/5.2.2'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''
xz=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME "XZ Utils"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "xz"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "5.2.2"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "XZ Utils 5.2.2"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "lasse.collin@tukaani.org"
#define PACKAGE_URL "http://tukaani.org/xz/"
#define NDEBUG 1
#define HAVE_ENCODER_LZMA1 1
#define HAVE_ENCODER_LZMA2 1
#define HAVE_ENCODER_DELTA 1
#define HAVE_ENCODER_X86 1
#define HAVE_ENCODER_POWERPC 1
#define HAVE_ENCODER_IA64 1
#define HAVE_ENCODER_ARM 1
#define HAVE_ENCODER_ARMTHUMB 1
#define HAVE_ENCODER_SPARC 1
#define HAVE_DECODER_LZMA1 1
#define HAVE_DECODER_LZMA2 1
#define HAVE_DECODER_DELTA 1
#define HAVE_DECODER_X86 1
#define HAVE_DECODER_POWERPC 1
#define HAVE_DECODER_IA64 1
#define HAVE_DECODER_ARM 1
#define HAVE_DECODER_ARMTHUMB 1
#define HAVE_DECODER_SPARC 1
#define HAVE_MF_HC3 1
#define HAVE_MF_HC4 1
#define HAVE_MF_BT2 1
#define HAVE_MF_BT3 1
#define HAVE_MF_BT4 1
#define HAVE_CHECK_CRC32 1
#define HAVE_CHECK_CRC64 1
#define HAVE_CHECK_SHA256 1
#define ASSUME_RAM 128
#define PACKAGE "xz"
#define VERSION "5.2.2"

configure: exit 77
```

If I was wrong, what's exactly the problem? Why is it caused? And most important, how do I fix it?

P.S. I'm running macOS Sierra (10.12) and Xcode-beta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More recent versions of Homebrew pass the `-no_weak_imports` flag to ld if Homebrew detects Xcode 8.0 or later, which ships with a version of ld which supports this flag (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/3727). However, ealier versions of Xcode 8 beta don't have this, causing ld to fail when autoconf tests the compiler.

There are a couple of solutions to this problem:

#### 1. Update Xcode to the latest beta (Recommended)

Assuming that you can download the latest beta from the App Store, installing it should also install the version of ld that works with Homebrew. This solution should be easier.

#### 2. Override the Homebrew checks for Xcode 8

The checks Homebrew makes for Xcode 8 are done in

```
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/extend/os/mac/extend/ENV/shared.rb
```

which contains

```
module SharedEnvExtension
  def no_weak_imports?
    return false unless compiler == :clang

    if MacOS::Xcode.version && MacOS::Xcode.version < "8.0"
      return false
    end

    if MacOS::CLT.version && MacOS::CLT.version < "8.0"
      return false
    end

    true
  end
end
```

Adding a `return false` after the function declaration prevents Homebrew from passing the `-no_weak_imports` flag, fixing the error:

```
module SharedEnvExtension
  def no_weak_imports?
    ## This fixes the issue
    ## CHANGE THIS BACK LATER
    return false
    ##
    return false unless compiler == :clang

    if MacOS::Xcode.version && MacOS::Xcode.version < "8.0"
      return false
    end

    if MacOS::CLT.version && MacOS::CLT.version < "8.0"
      return false
    end

    true
  end
end
```

If you take this approach, you should:
1. Make a note somewhere that you've done it, and change it back when you update Xcode
2. Be on the lookout for errors when upgrading Homebrew - I'm not sure of the details, but it's possible that a `brew upgrade` will either break or overwrite it.

Comment: The `.xip` file gave me some problems, but on the fourth re-download it worked! Thanks :)